# Update Dialogflow "Transfer Call" field from backend ( Node.js )

Tags: dialogflow-es

I try to update phone number in  "Transfer Call" field under "Responses" tab ("TELEPHONY" -> "ADD RESPONSES" button ) for given intent using Node.js  but I cannot. 
New update removes old "Transfer Call" field with the old  phone number (which I created by hand in console for testing purposes)
Please help

## Here is example code:

```
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow')
const intentsClient = new dialogflow.IntentsClient({ keyFilename: 'key.json' })

const fulfillmentMessages = [ { platform: 'TELEPHONY',
telephonySynthesizeSpeech: { text: 'Hello World' } },
{ platform: 'TELEPHONY',
telephonyTransferCall: { phoneNumber: '+12132954242' } },
{ text: { text: [ '' ] } } ]

const intent = {
name: 'projects/example/agent/intents/2ef3e0b6-6cd7-4d5b-a8ca-ce11111125e019',
displayName: 'Test',
fulfillmentMessages: fulfillmentMessages
}

const updateIntentRequest = { intent: intent }

intentsClient.updateIntent(updateIntentRequest).then((data) =>{ console.log(data)}, (e) => { 
console.log(e) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Detailed response can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/dialogflow-enterprise-edition-users/KB6IlVeoS4c/TUd2ssaVDwAJ) however heres the correct code sample (tested and working)

```
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
const intentsClient = new dialogflow.v2beta1.IntentsClient({ keyFilename: 'key.json' }) //Note that dialogflow will be using v2beta1 api

const message_to_set = [
  { 
      platform: 10,
      telephonySynthesizeSpeech: {
             text : 'Hello World'
         },
         telephonyTransferCall: {
             phoneNumber: '+12132954242'
      }
  }
]

const intent = {
   name: 'projects/example/agent/intents/2ef3e0b6-6cd7-4d5b-a8ca-ce11111125e019',
   displayName: 'Forward',
   messages: message_to_set //Note parameter was switched from fulfillmentMessages to messages
}

const updateIntentRequest = { intent: intent }

intentsClient.updateIntent(updateIntentRequest).then((data) =>{ console.log(data)}, (e) => { console.log(e) })
```

Comment: Thank you Gurkomal.

Comment: Will check it out